# How to enable mouse tracking on a QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using a `QWindow` (Not a `QMainWindow`) with OpenGL. I need to use a `QWindow` to correctly control the OGL context.

I'm trying to follow the [Scribble](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) example to implement something similar to panning, but I can't find a paradigmatic way to trigger the `mouseMoveEvent()`.

How can I get a "tooltip" effect where `mouseMoveEvent()` is constantly triggered, similar to `setMouseTracking()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me. I created a test program with a MainWindow that inherits `QWindow` instead of QMainWindow, and handles the mouse move event to print the cursor position:

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    qDebug("%d, %d", e->pos().x(), e->pos().y());
}
```

It works, as I move the mouse I get events even without pressing any mouse buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If mouse tracking is disabled (the default), the widget only receives mouse move events when at least one mouse button is pressed while the mouse is being moved.

you can call  `hasMouseTracking()` or `setMouseTracking()` to control mouse's tracing state.

When mouse is traced, `mouseMoveEvent()` will be called, and you can reimpletment `mouseMoveEven()` to acquire mouse position, just as @sashoalm did.

BTW, mouse event is always transfered to your app, but filtered by it's parent or itself. You can reimpletment `eventFilter()` to code your own filter.